# Taking a word from a string inside another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, my problem is I am trying to separate lines in a text file, then separate each word into different objects, one being whole_name, and the other being score.

Example of text document:

```
Adam Smith 89
Dave Jones 70
John Doe 54
Jane Doe 96
```

Notice how each line is a different name followed by a score.

Here's the important part of the code I have which is failing:

```
for line in infile.readlines():
    objects = line.split(" ")
    whole_name = objects[0:2]
```

What this is giving me is the last name, Jane Doe and that's it. I don't know how to get the other names from the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
whole_names = list()
for line in infile.readlines():
    objects = line.split(" ")
    whole_names.append(' '.join(objects[0:2]))
```

You keep overwriting the `whole_name` variable hence you only get the last name. Make `whole_names` a list and append all names to it. This way at the very end, `whole_names` will be a list of strings containing all the names.